# How to make User Logout After Countdown React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to achieve making the user log out after the countdown ends, I'm sorry because I am just new in react still learning, anyways this is my code. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it. Has an error that says TypeError: this.props.onLogout is not a function :)

My Code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Countdown from "react-countdown";
import {
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { logoutUser } from '../../../actions/authActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';


export class OnlineOrders extends Component {
 
  onLogout = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logoutUser();
  };

  render() {
 
    
    const renderer = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
      if (completed) {
        this.props.onLogout();
        return <>
          <Redirect to='/billing/plans' />
        
        </>;
      } else {
        return (
          <span>
            {days}:{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
          </span>
        );
      }
    };

    return (
      <>
          <div className='note primary'>
            You have <strong><Countdown date={Date.now() + 5000} renderer={renderer} /></strong>  remaining on your free trial.
                <a href='/billing/plans'> Activate Now</a> to stay alive!
              </div>
      </>
    );
  };
}

OnlineOrders.propTypes = {
  logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { logoutUser })(OnlineOrders);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to invoke `onLogout` correctly.

```
if (completed) {
  this.onLogout();
  return <Redirect to='/billing/plans' />;
} else {
  return (
    <span>
      {days}:{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
    </span>
  );
}
```

Side note: You can invoke the callback from props directly and save a function declaration.

```
if (completed) {
  this.props.logoutUser();
  return <Redirect to='/billing/plans' />;
} else {
  return (
    <span>
      {days}:{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
    </span>
  );
}
```

The `else` is actually also superfluous, it can be removed.

```
const renderer = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
  if (completed) {
    this.props.logoutUser();
    return <Redirect to='/billing/plans' />;
  }
  return (
    <span>
      {days}:{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}
    </span>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering but it says that this.props.logoutUser is not a function @Drew Reese

Comment: @AlifKhan `this.props.logoutUser();` was code taken directly from your snippet. That error means either (1) that literally `this.props.logoutUser();` isn't a function, i.e. it is something else that isn't a function and can't be called as one, or (2) that `this.props.logoutUser();` is undefined because it wasn't passed as a prop to the `OnlineOrders` component. If you use `this.onLogout();` does the same issue persist?

Comment: sorry my mistake forgot to import an import { logoutUser } from '../../../actions/authActions';

Comment: when I use this.onLogout(); it has the same error @Drew Reese

Comment: @AlifKhan Using redux? Is your `logoutUser` wrapped in a call to `dispatch`? Is your component connected to your redux store? If you can update your question to include the entire component code I can help further.

Comment: @AlifKhan You export the unconnected component (named export) and also export the connected component as the default export. Please ensure you are importing the default connected component wherever you are trying to render it. The unconnected component won't have `logoutUser` injected as a prop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226647/discussion-between-alif-khan-and-drew-reese).